# How does non-C# plugins rules/profiles work (within CI - Jenkins)

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a repository with a C# (.NET Core Web API) project and a Typescript (Angular) project.

We use the MSBuild plugin to perform analysis during the build via Jenkins. This then reports back to our SonarQube instance. The MSBuild plugins correctly detects that there are other code types (including Typescript, HTML, CSS, etc...) and runs that analysis as well.

However, for the other code types, all rules available on the SonarQube server seem to be reported on. This should not be the case as we have a custom profile assigned to the project that has rules disabled (eg: we disable the missing file header as it is not required in our environment).

I have used Visual Studio with the SonarLint connected mode plugin to pull down the C# rules set within our SonarQube instance. This works great and via Jenkins the correct results based on the custom profile.

Maybe it something I haven't configured correctly for the other code types? Any ideas anyone?

If you need any Jenkins builds logs/output/config, just let me know and I can upload it.

Comment: Please check your analysis log for lines that start with `INFO: Quality profile for [language]: ...` and [edit] your post to include those lines.